# SharePoint 2010 jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a custom field type with jQuery autocomplete functionality. But I'm really stuck now.

I want to use a WCF REST service that returns the necessary data. The data is not stored in a list. It stored in a DB2 database.

With ASP.NET MVC this is peanuts, but in SharePoint I'm really struggling.

Does anyone have a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not mentioning exactly 'how' it is not working, but I think that it may be down to preventing [Cross Site Scripting attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

I am guessing that your ASP.NET application is calling your REST service from the same domain whereas in SharePoint it would be under a different domain, and hence your browser is preventing it.

In JQuery you can get around this by calling JSONP (JSON with Padding) rather than
[JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

The good news is that defining your WCF service to use [JSONP is much easier in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx)

If you can't get this to work, I suggest updating your question with your JQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this controls: http://anjlab.com/en/project/sharepoint2010-richcontrols

Comment: That look great, but my data is stored in a DB2 database. That's why I wanted to use a WCF Rest service as a backend.